# I got an error while using StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

The int input represents a number k, and the method should replace the kth occurrence of the first char input with the second char input. If the first char does not occur at least k times, then nothing is replaced.

```
public class HW2{
    public static String replaceKth(char a, char b, int k, String c){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int occ = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length(); i = i + 1){
            if (c.charAt(i) == a){
                occ = occ + 1;
                if(occ == k){
                    builder.setCharAt(i, b);
                }
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

When I tried to test:

```
HW2.replaceKth(a, b, 3, "aabaa")
Static Error: Undefined name 'a'
```

yep I define `a` and another error appears

```
HW2.replaceKth('a', 'a', 3, "aabaa")
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.setCharAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:347)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.setCharAt(StringBuilder.java:55)
    at HW2.replaceKth(HW2.java:15)
>
```

Comment: Did you define `a` first?

Comment: Yep, and what did you declare `a` as in the caller?  Or did you mean to do something like `HW2.replaceKth('a', 'b', 3, "aabaa")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set the builder instance equal to your `String` object that you wanted to modify.

```
public static String replaceKth(char a, char b, int k, String c){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(c);
    int occ = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++){
        if (c.charAt(i) == a){
            occ = occ + 1;
            if(occ == k){
                builder.setCharAt(i, b);
            }
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without single-quotes, `a` is just a variable name, which appears not to be defined here.

When you call `replaceKth`, either define `a` and `b` to be a `char`s with specific values, or pass `char` literals, each enclosed in single-quotes.

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';
```

OR

```
HW2.replaceKth('a', 'b', 3, "aabaa");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error is because you are sending a **variable** `a` and not a letter a.

`a` is a variable you didn't declare. Either make one, or use quotes around the letters when calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting your `String` to `StringBuilder`

Change the code line as

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(c);
```

you can do like this to replace the character at an index

```
public class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(StringTest.replaceKth('a', 'b', 3, "aabaa"));
    }

    public static String replaceKth(char a, char b, int k, String c){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(c);
        if(builder.charAt(k)==a){
            builder.setCharAt(k, b);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```